# Go Прием udp пакетов. Аналог tcpdump

Tags: golang, udp, tcpdump, goland

Есть программа которая посылает UDP пакеты на внешние адреса соответственно другим ЭВМ.

Нужен приемник этих пакетов на той же машине что их отправляет,
аналог команды "tcpdump  port 3000" на Goland.

Попытка установить адрес ":3000" и потом слушать не дает результата.

Может есть какие мысли????
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Мысли такие - попробовать использовать пакет `net` и функции из него `ListenUDP` и какую-нибудь из функций `func (*UDPConn) ReadXxx`. Если не получится, добавить вывод отладочной информации и попробовать ещё раз. Если и тогда не получится, то создать на стэкоферфлоу вопрос, куда поместить и программу, и отладочную информацию и все ошибки.

Comment: Монитор трафика в Go можно сделать на пакете https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/gopacket